# Updating Dynamics CRM entries in C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to find out how to update data in Dynamics CRM and I fail miserably.

```
private const string Url = "*****/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/";
    private const string userName = "username";
    private const string password = "password";
    private readonly HttpClientHandler _handler;
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    _handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

   public void Put()
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent("<feed><entry><content><m:properties><d:Address1_Country>NEW VALUE</d:Address1_Country></m:properties></content></entry></feed>");

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(_handler))
        {
            client.PutAsync(Url + "AccountSet(guid'182df667-c4f6-e111-8042-0050568e0828')", content).Result;
        }
    }
```

The response I get is:

response = {StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
  Persistent-Auth: true
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Tue, 10 Mar 2015 10:22:07 GMT
  Server: Micr...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using the Dynamics CRM SDK DLLs for this operation?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use OData endpoint that would not work outside of CRM webresources. Try to use SOAP endpoint for your purpose:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334754.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx